# Is Google Web Search API ok to use, even though its deprecated?

Tags: google-search

I want to use the [Google Web Search API](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/?hl=en) for Google image searches on a web page. Is it ok to use the deprecated API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should be fine. Good Luck!